# Python code not achieving correct output?

Tags: python

I have a project due for school that is working except for one part. I have a list with birthdays where I go through each one and get the age, then class them as adult, child, senior or baby/toddler. Toddlers/babies must have at least one adult/senior with them, which I have taken into account near the end of the code. I have a running total and general count for each age group. However, when a baby/toddler is submitted without a parent, I have tried decreasing the counts to eliminate the entry as it isn't valid but at the end it prints out?

```
import datetime
# import datetime fucntion for use in determining ages
today = datetime.datetime.now()
# set variable for today's current date
thirtyone = ['01', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12']
# distinguish which months have 31 days to validate date
thirty = ['04', '06', '09', '11']
# distinguish which months have 30 days to validate date
adults = 0
# total number of adults for one booking
children = 0
# total number of children for one booking
baby_todds = 0
# total number of babies for one booking
seniors = 0
# total number of seniors for one booking
a_cost = 0
# total cost of adults for one booking
c_cost = 0
# total cost of children for one booking
s_cost = 0
# total cost of seniors for one booking
tot_adult = 0
# running total for adults over day
tot_child = 0
# running total for children over day
tot_bab = 0
# running total for babies over day
tot_sen = 0
# running total for seniors over day
total_birthdays = []
while True:
    # run validation for total number of people
        total_people = input('How many people are going?: ').strip()
        # get total number of people and strip to remove unnecessary spacing
        if total_people == '':
        # if total people entered as blank
            print("* you haven't entered anything.")
            # let user know error
            continue
            # go back to top of loop to re-enter total number of people
        elif re.search('[a-z]', total_people):
        # if there are lowercase letters in total people
            print("* entry can't contain letters. please try again with only numbers.")
            # let user know error
            continue
            # go back to top of loop to re-enter total number of people
        elif re.search('[A-Z]', total_people):
        # if there are uppercase letters in total people
            print("* entry can't contain letters. please try again with only numbers.")
            # let user know error
            continue
            # go back to top of loop to re-enter total number of people
        elif re.search('[~!@#£€$¢¥§%^&*()\\-_+={}[]|/:;"\'<>,.?]', total_people):
        # if there are symbols in total people
            print("* entry can't contain letters. please try again with only numbers.")
            # let user know error
            continue
            # go back to top of loop to re-enter total number of people
        elif int(total_people) < 1:
        # if total people as an integer is less than 1
            print('* must have at least one guest.')
            # let user know error
            continue
            # go back to top of loop to re-enter total number of people
        else:
        # if none of these conditions apply, entry is valid
            break
            # exit out of while loop
total_people = int(total_people)
# convert total people to integer for furture use
x = True
# set x variable to true
while x == True:
# while x is true, loop can run
    for person in range(total_people):
    # for each person as one of total people
        while True:
        # run validation for birthday
            birthday = input('Birthday (MM/DD/YYYY): ').strip()
            # get total number of people and strip to remove unnecessary spacing
            if birthday == '':
            # if birthday entered as blank
                print("* you haven't entered anything.")
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif re.search('[a-z]', birthday):
            # if there are lowercase letters in birthday
                print("* birthday can't contain letters. please try again in (MM/DD/YYYY) format.")
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif re.search('[A-Z]', birthday):
            # if there are uppercase letters in birthday
                print("* birthday can't contain letters. please try again in (MM/DD/YYYY) format.")
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif re.search('[~!@#£€$¢¥§%^&*()\\-_+={}[]|/:;"\'<>,.?]', birthday):
            # if there are symbols in birthday
                print("* birthday can't contain an invalid symbol. please try again in (MM/DD/YYYY) format.")
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            try:
            # if content is correct, check format
                datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y')
                # if birthday can be made into a date format, is valid
            except ValueError:
            # if birthday can't be made into a date format
                print('* incorrect date format, should be (MM/DD/YYYY)')
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            birthdays = birthday.split('/')
            # format now correct, split to run validation for dates
            if len(birthdays[2]) != 4:
            # if the year does not have 4 numbers
                print('* invalid year. please try again.')
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif int(birthdays[2]) < 1900:
            # if the year is less thyan 1900
                print('* invalid year. please try again.')
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y') > today:
            # if the date entered is in the future
                print('* invalid date. please try again.')
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif birthdays[0] in thirtyone:
            # if the month is in the list of months with thirty one days
                if int(birthdays[1]) <= 31:
                # if the day is less than or equal to 31
                    break
                    # birthday is valid, exit out of loop
                else:
                # if the day is more than 31
                    print('* invalid day. please try again.')
                    # let user know error
                    continue
                    # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif birthdays[0] in thirty:
            # if the month is in the list of months with thirty days
                if int(birthdays[1]) <= 30 :
                # if the day is less than or equal to 30
                    break
                    # birthday is valid, exit out of loop
                else:
                # if the day is more than 30
                    print('* invalid day. please try again.')
                    # let user know error
                    continue
                    # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
            elif birthdays[0] == '02':
            # if the month is february
                if int(birthdays[1]) > 29:
                # if the day is more than 29
                    print('* invalid date. please try again.')
                    # let user know error
                    continue
                    # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
                elif int(birthdays[1]) == 29:
                # if the day is exactly equal to 29
                    if int(birthdays[2]) % 4 == 0 and int(birthdays[2]) % 10 != 0:
                    # if the year is exactly divisible by 4 but not by 10
                        break
                        # birthday is valid (valid leap year), exit out of loop
                    else:
                    # if the year is not a valid leap year
                        print('* invalid date. please try again.')
                        # let user know error
                        continue
                        # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
                else:
                # if the day is less than or equal to 28
                    break
                    # birthday is valid, exit out of loop
            else:
            # if the month is more than 12
                print('* invalid month. please try again.')
                # let user know error
                continue
                # go back to top of loop to re-enter birthday
        total_birthdays.append(birthday)
        # append validated birthday to total birthdays list
    for birthday in total_birthdays:
    # for each valid birthday in total birthdays loop
        birth_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,'%m/%d/%Y')
        # convert birthday to workable date format
        age = today - birth_date
        # take birthday away from today's date
        age = age.total_seconds()/(365*24*3600)
        # find numerical value for age by dividing total seconds of answer by seconds in one year
        if age < 3:
        # if age is less than 3
            baby_todds += 1
            # add 1 to babies total
            tot_bab += 1
            # add 1 to babies running total
        elif age < 12:
        # if age is less than 12
            children += 1
            # add 1 to children total
            tot_child += 1
            # add 1 to children running total
        elif age >= 65:
        # if age is greater than or equal to 65
            seniors += 1
            # add 1 to seniors total
            tot_sen += 1
            # add 1 to seniors running total
        else:
        # if none of above, is adult by default
            adults += 1
            # add 1 to adults total
            tot_adult += 1
            # add 1 to adults running total
    if baby_todds == 0:
        x = False
    elif baby_todds > 0 and (adults > 0 or seniors > 0):
    # if there are babies/toddlers but at least one adult/senior
        x = False
        # suitable parental advisory, break out of loop
    else:
    # if there are babies/toddlers but no adults or seniors
        print()
        # add break
        print('Babies and toddlers can not go unsupervised.')
        # let user know error
        print('Please re-enter appropriate birth dates.')
        # request to re-enter birthdays
        tot_bab -= baby_todds
        # removes last entry from running total for babies/toddlers
        baby_todds = 0
        # resets baby/toddlers to 0
        tot_child -= children
        # removes last entry from running total for children
        children = 0
        # resets children to 0
        x = True
        # go right back to start of loop
print(baby_todds)
print(tot_bab)
print(children)
print(tot_child)
```

e.g. I enter the birthdays 02/19/2020 and 03/20/2019 and it comes up with error (no adults/seniors) and asks for me to enter it again. So I enter 02/19/1990 and 02/29/20000 which is valid. But baby_todds and tot_bab both print out as 2 still? I swear I have tried everything but nothing is working. It's like it completely skips over that code.

Comment: @ppwater Okay, I tried to add everything relevant to that section of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you return to the start of the loop and receive new dates from the user, you don't create a new `total_birthdays` list, you append the one you created before the loop, which also contains the dates from the previous iteration of the loop. if you will move the line `total_birthdays = []` to inside the loop that read dates from the user, it should work.